# Gstreamer: How to read a structure inside the property of an element

Tags: tensorflow, gstreamer, face-detection

First of all , I am very new to G-streamer and it would be very helpful if someone could just give me a simple explanation about what I'm asking here.

So there is a pipeline which feeds raw video from a camera source to Tensorflow element which detects faces and stores the Face ROI coordinates into a structure and also update some kind of metadata. After this , there's a display overlay element which will draw a bounding box using the inference results read from metadata updated by the Tensor Flow  element.

Tensorflow (plugin) --> Post processing (property) --> Detection (structure)

To put it simply , I need to get the values of structure which will get updated on each face detection when the pipeline is running. I checked `gst_bin_get_by_name()` + `g_object_class_find_property()`+`g_object_get ()` API combination , but seems like it can only read the state like Enabled/disabled,a parameter string etc from the property.
I don't know I was able to convey my requirement properly.
Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can use nnstreamer for your application: https://github.com/nnstreamer/nnstreamer

The corresponding (GStreamer) pipeline would look like (w/ a lot of assumptions):

```
v4l2src ! # assuming a USB camera
tee name=rawvideo ! queue max-buffer-size=2 leaky=2 !
videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! # basic preprocessing for live video
video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=300,height=300 ! # another assumption on your model
tensor_converter ! # now, the format becomes video/x-raw --> other/tensors
tensor_transform mode=arithmetic option=typecast:float32,div:255 ! # you may add different mode & options for your pre-processing needs (e.g., transpose, standardization, ...)
tensor_filter framework=tensorflow model=YOURMODELFILE.pb !
tee name=result ! appsink name=yourappcangetrawstructuretensors
result. ! tensor_decoder mode=bounding_boxes option..... ! # if the correponsing subplugin exists for the given structure, you can simply designate here. otherwise, you can write your own code and attach here.
mix.sink_1

rawvideo. ! queue leaky=2 max-buffer-size=2 ! mix.sink_0

### use composite or videomixer to overlay boundingboxes
compositor name=mix sink_0::zorder=1 sink_1::zorder=2 ! videoconvert !
autovideosink ## you may use different video sink for your systems.
```

In other words, you can have separated streams of the "structure" (output of tensorflow) and the "video" (input of tensorflow or the original video stream) and merge them later at compositor in the above example.